# Can't tell if my html form is incorrect or my post route handler

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm attempting to setup my html so that when the user submits the form i created it will be handled by the post route handler in order to save the data into the mondo DB.

I tried setting up my post route handler to take req.body.service but i believe that the html isnt passing any data because i used a console.log() once it arrives to the post route handler and nothing is written.

// survey.ejs

```
<h2>Feedback Survey</h2>
    <div>
        Please select the service provider you signed up for:<br>
    </div>
    <form action="/survey" action="POST" id="service">
        <select name="service" id="service" required>
            <option value="" disabled selected hidden>Type to search </option>
            <option value="option1">option1</option>
            <option value="option2">option2</option>
            <option value="option3">option3</option>
        </select>
        <br>
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
    <a href="/index">Go back home</a>
</body>
</html>
```

// routes/survey.js

```
const express = require('express')
const router = express.Router()
const Survey = require('../models/survey')

router.post('/', async(req, res) => {

    console.log('Before try catch statement')

    try{

        const data={
            service: req.body.service
        }

        await Survey.insertMany[(data)]

        res.render('index')

    }catch (e){

        console.log(e)
    }
})

module.exports = router
```

```
// models/survey

const mongoose = require ('mongoose')

const surveySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    service: {
        type: String, 
        required: true
    }
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('Survey', surveySchema)
```

// middleware

```
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false}))
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a several things wrong.

First, the route on your server for your form is `/survey` (from `action="/survey"`) in the `<form>` tag, but you only show a route for `/`.

Second, `action="POST"` should be `method="POST"` in your `<form>` tag.

Third, your data will arrive as a content-type of `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` and you will need middleware on your express server to read that content-type.

```
app.use(express.urlencoded());
```

And, that middleware needs to be either on the specific route for the form or registered before that route.

---

This also assumes that you are registering the router you show with your Express server too (the code you've disclosed does not currently show that).

Comment: Thank you for catching that was a silly oversight on my part. So the routes do work and i can confirm by using a console.log() once the route is entered. The way i have the routes set up is intentional so I know the issue doesn't reside there. I still can't see the data stored after being submitted by the user in my DB which is the result i'm looking for.

Comment: @eddie - Then, this now sounds like basic debugging on your part.  What does `console.log(req.body.service)` show?  If that's correct, then apparently, `await Survey.insertMany[(data)]` isn't inserting the data you want into your database so you will have to further debug that.

Comment: okay got it.. ill mess with it a bit more and see what i can find out. I also do have middleware in my server.js file to handle the data which is //app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false}))

Answer (score 0):

So after looking over my code i was able to figure out the two issues that i had that was stopping me from passing the data from the submission form.

1. In my html I had `action=""` written twice.
2. In my routes/survey when passing the variable i need to type ([data]).